# Why am I not seeing any data file received in my PHP file coming from AngularJS $http.post

Tags: php, angularjs, forms, post, http-post

**I am trying to post a file (will be of type pdf or image), uploaded by the user in a form. The file will be taken by an AngularJS directive set 'onChange', sent through 'myPostr' function which is supposed to post my file to 'api/' so it can be received by PHP. Atm, PHP echoes empty arrays, atleast having the headers - 200 OK.**

This my HTML:

```
<input name="file" class="form-control-file" my-directive type="file" accept="application/pdf">
```

This my simplified AngularJS script:

```
application.directive('myDirective', function(myPostr){
    return{
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: true,
        link: function(scope, element){
            element.bind('change', function(){
                if (element[0].files[0].type == 'application/pdf') { 
                    var form = new FormData();
                    form.append('form', element[0].files[0])
                    myPostr(form, function(callback){
                        console.log(callback);
                    }) //or imagetype to be implemented


application.factory('myPostr', function($http){
    return function (data, callback) {
        $http.post('api/', {
            data: data,
            headers: {'Content-type':undefined}
        })}
});
```

*'myPoster' works fine for json data (form variables)*

This are the multiple ways I've tried in PHP to display the received data:

```
//isset($_FILES['file']) returns false

$response = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'),true);

header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($response);  //or
//echo json_encode($_FILES);
```

All return [this in the network console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WOjdJ.png)

Extra info: [these are the console logs of the uploaded files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1OmeE.png)

Comment: If you're trying to send a file, then using json_decode makes no sense - a file is not JSON data, it's binary data.

Comment: Well echoing $_FILES doesnt return anything either...